# Java Swing Internal Frame As Dialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jinternalframe

I have created one project in netbeans. I have one internal frame, which I want to be displayed as dialog. Please help me.
Note:I have used windows look and feel.

Comment: *"Note:I have used windows look and feel."*  Don't do that, set it to [UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#getSystemLookAndFeelClassName%28%29).  Your Linux & OS X users will thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a `java.awt.Dialog` or `javax.swing.JDialog`.  Instead look to the [`JOptionPane` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#method_summary) that start with '`showInternal..`'.  E.G.

[image: Internal Dialog]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class InternalDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // the GUI as seen by the user (without frame)
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 3, 2, 3));

                JDesktopPane dtp = new JDesktopPane();
                gui.add(dtp);

                ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Component c= (Component)e.getSource();
                        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(c, "Message");
                    }
                };
                for (int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
                    JInternalFrame jif = new JInternalFrame();
                    dtp.add(jif);
                    jif.setLocation(new Point(ii*30, ii*20));
                    jif.setSize(200,50);
                    jif.setVisible(true);

                    JButton b = new JButton("Click me!");
                    b.addActionListener(listener);
                    jif.add(b);
                }

                // TODO!
                gui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 150));
                gui.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
                f.add(gui);
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson, is this the only way? the method `showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)` does not have an internal counterpart.

Comment: @ryvantage (shrugs)  I don't use internal frames much.  You might look to use [`JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) instead..

Answer (score 0):

**Swing** has its own native look and feel. You can document yourself on `JDialog` [right here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). For platform look and feel, try using **SWT**. Next time please be more specific with your question. Good luck.